# Rails override associations in subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I need to have a new class CountryUser inherited from User and the difference between them is one single association

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_sites
  has_many :sites, through: :user_sites
  has_many :countries, through: :sites
end
```

**CountryUser**

```
class CountryUser < User
  has_many :user_countries
  has_many :countries, through: :user_countries
end
```

When Im a CountryUser I get my Countries through a user_countries table and if Im a normal Users I get my countries through the sites im assigned to.

But the problem is that `CountryUser.first.countries` always shows the relation as if it was a normal User (through sites)

Isnt it possible to override associations in sublclasses? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using single table inheritance/STI?

`User` and `CountryUser` have different associations so re-factor your common user model concerns into a base user class `User` and create two subclasses `SiteUser` and `CountryUser` as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # common user model concerns here
end

class SiteUser < User
  has_many :user_sites
  has_many :sites, through: :user_sites
  has_many :countries, through: :sites
end

class CountryUser < User
  has_many :user_countries
  has_many :countries, through: :user_countries
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this was my intention too.. but one more question.. how would you do a login. f.e. if a SiteUser logs in the current_user should be SiteUser not User (depending on the role) ... is there a way to override the current_user helper to take either one or the other model?

Comment: If you are using say Devise for authentication it should be finding user models based on the users name/email. The database table is the same regardless of the specific user class, so it depends which model you have configured Devise for (assuming you are using devise).